# I only have the bin folder in my .minecraft folder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I deleted my .minecraft folder thinking, "oh yeah it'll all just Re-Download when i start minecraft up". I was wrong. I looked in my .minecraft folder and all that is in there is the bin folder and the last login file. I have no idea what to do... Can someone help me with this?

Just letting you know that I emptied my recycle bin after I deleted it. I also have a premium account and it worked fine for the past year.

Comment: I just removed my .minecraft folder, launched minecraft. At first only the bin folder and lastlogin file popped up, but after waiting a little while, the rest of the folders were created. Did you exit minecraft before it reached the title screen?

Comment: Also, this appears to be an exact duplicate of "[I only have a bin folder in my .minecraft folder!](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82281/i-only-have-a-bin-folder-in-my-minecraft-folder)" within the span of only a few days, but the user name is different. Any relation to user [Kobe Johnson](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/31546/kobe-johnson)?

Answer (score 4):

To re-download your .minecraft folder you have to do a force update. You can find that by clicking "options" in the launcher. Without a forced update, the launcher might only check to make sure you have the latest minecraft.jar and will only download that if it's out of date or missing entirely.

If you deleted it when minecraft is open, Delete the folder again and force update.