# I accidentally deleted my .minecraft folder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was messing around with some computer files and accidentally deleted my `.minecraft` folder. There was a lot of important stuff in there, and I don't know how to get it back. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think this might be the solution to your problem:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82484/i-only-have-the-bin-folder-in-my-minecraft-folder?rq=1

Comment: @CliffordO.Martinez that doesn't restore saves though?

Comment: keyword 'undelete'. Undeleting files is a difficult and unreliable process though. But first check the recycle bin, maybe it's still in there.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you deleted it you'd better hope it's in your recycling bin. If it is, just press "restore". If it isn't, well, you're in trouble.

Unless you have re-installed windows recently, then there is no way to restore your saves and folders, unless you have them backed up of course :P

If by some mystery you HAVE reinstalled windows recently, simple look for your windows.old folder, and inside that should be a .minecraft folder which is identical to the .minecraft folder you had when you reinstalled the OS.